# Настройка лаунчера в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, settings

Решил перейти с Kubuntu на Ubuntu. Скачал дистрибутив и поставил.
Встал вопрос как настроить лаунчер что бы можно было запускать быстро мои программы. 
Сначало показалось просто, запустить программу из консоли а затем залочить приложение на лаунчере. С некоторыми приложениями это прошло, а например с Android Studio и Intellij Idea нет. Точнее они залочились но, вместо иконки после закрытия программы возникает знак вопроса и при следующий попытки запустить они не запускаются.
Стал копать в интернете, там пишут что нужно создать файл app.desktop и положить его в директорию

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

Сделал файл такой файл:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Android Studio
Comment=Android Studio
Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Exec=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Кнопка на лаунчере не появилась.
Есть ли какие то иные пути как решить эту проблему или что я тут делаю не так?

Comment: Как по-русски будет "лаунчер"?

Comment: @edem это тут при чем? Launcher - в данном контексте  панель для запуска

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл вы правильно создали. Только он добавляет не кнопку запуска, а приложение в список приложений (тот, что появляется по нажатию <kbd>Win</kbd>). Теперь вам нужно запустить приложение оттуда, и вот уже его иконку можно будет к панели прикрепить.
Если приложение в списке ещё не появилось, возможно, надо пнуть unity, но как это делается, я не знаю, так что могу лишь посоветовать перелогиниться.

И кстати, последние версии Idea умеют сами добавлять себя в список приложений (`Tools` > `Create Desktop Entry...`).

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь я понял!